# Save app rating offline

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

When user clicks “Rate this app” button and internet connection is unavailable I want to save the app rating offline, so that when device is connected to internet the rating is submitted in background. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to submit a rating to Play Store this way, as it require you to open the app page on Play Store and it is not possible without an internet connection. Your user will get a no internet connection error. What you can do is keep the user's rating in your app persistently and suggest the user to rate in store when internet connection is available.